# MySQL - Reinstalled because password forgotten but cannot connect to server (Mac OS)

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I reinstalled MySQL Server and Workbench on my Mac because I forgot my password. I successfully did; however, I get this message saying that I cannot connect to the server.

```
2018-10-21 17:10:13 - Starting server...
2018-10-21 17:10:13 - Executing 'launchctl load -F/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist'
2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Checking server status...
2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) (2003)
2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Assuming server is not running
2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Starting server...
2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Executing 'launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist'
2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Start server: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.my
2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Start server: sql.mysqld.plist: service already loaded

2018-10-21 17:10:18 - Server start done.
2018-10-21 17:10:22 - Checking server status...
2018-10-21 17:10:22 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2018-10-21 17:10:22 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) (2003)
2018-10-21 17:10:22 - Assuming server is not running
```

Can anyone give me a clue as to how to resolve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check if the mysql is up and running:

```
ps -aux | grep mysql
```

if it is not, use the command

```
mysql.server start
```

or try to restart the service

```
mysql.server restart
```

and try to connect again